# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) in C++ Deck class

Tags: c++

I want to make a class called `Deck` out of a class of `Cards`. However, whenever I try to see what I've put in my `Deck`, I get an error that says `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. How can I fix this? I've read from other questions that my program might be trying to access memory that hasn't been allocated, but I don't know where that is happening. This is the code I wrote:

deck.h:

```
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H

#include <vector>

#include "card.h"

class Deck
{

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, Deck &);

    public:
            Deck();

            void shuffle();

    private:

            vector<Card> myDeck;
};

#endif
```

Deck.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "deck.h"
#include "card.h"

Deck::Deck()
{

    for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
            for(int j = 1; j <= 13; j++)
            {
                    Card myCard(j,i);
                    myDeck.push_back(myCard);
            }
    }
}

void Deck::shuffle()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
            Card temp(1,1);
            int swapID = rand() % 52;

            temp = this->myDeck[i];
            this->myDeck[i] = this->myDeck[swapID];
            this->myDeck[swapID] = temp;
    }
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Deck &theDeck)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
           cout << theDeck.myDeck[i];
    }
}
```

card.h:

```
#ifndef CARDS_H
#define CARDS_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Card {

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, Card &);

    public:
            Card(int face, int suit);

            void showCard();

    private:

            string face;
            string suit;

            void processFace(int value);
            void processSuit(int suit);
};

#endif
```

card.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "card.h"

using namespace std;

Card::Card(int face, int suit)
{
processFace(face);
processSuit(suit);

cout << "New card created" << endl;
}

void Card::showCard()
{
cout << "This is the " << this->face << " of " << this->suit << endl;
}

void Card::processFace(int value)
{

    switch(value)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        face = "Ace";
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        face = "2";
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        face = "3";
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        face = "4";
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        face = "5";
        break;
    }
    case 6:
    {
        face = "6";
        break;
    }
    case 7:
    {
        face = "8";
        break;
    }
    case 9:
    {
        face = "9";
        break;
    }
    case 10:
    {
        face = "10";
        break;
    }
    case 11:
    {
        face = "Jack";
        break;
    }
    case 12:
    {
        face = "Queen";
        break;
    }
    case 13:
    {
        face = "King";
        break;
    }
}
}

void Card::processSuit(int decider)
{
switch(decider)
{
    case 1:
    {
        suit = "Hearts";
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        suit = "Diamonds";
        break;
    }
    case 3: 
    {
        suit = "Clubs";
        break;
    }
    case 4: 
    {
        suit = "Spades";
        break;
    }
}
}


ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Card &myCard)
{
output << myCard.face << " of " << myCard.suit << endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "card.h"
#include "deck.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Deck mainDeck;

    cout << mainDeck << endl << endl;

}
```

Comment: safe way is check swapID generated before index it

Comment: Please post the header files too.

Comment: And `Card` type definition.

Comment: Do you know that this is a bad way to shuffle a deck of cards? (hint... there are `52!` different ways to shuffle and you're picking uniformly from `pow(52, 52)` that is not a multiple of `52!`)

Comment: What is a better way to do it? I'm curious.

Comment: @rafafan2010 [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle). Just do `std::random_shuffle(myDeck.begin(), myDeck.end());`: no handwritten loop, no "manual swap", and of course, correctness =) (don't forget to add a `#include <algorithm>`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Deck &theDeck)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
           cout << theDeck.myDeck[i];
    }
}
```

should return `ostream&`, but it is not returning anything. Also, you should call `operator<<` on `output` and not on the `cout` (you will pass `cout` to this method):

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Deck &theDeck)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
           output << theDeck.myDeck[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Also, make sure that the `operator<<` for `Card` type is properly written.

Comment: ... which is a point for the repeated: **Enable warnings**. With `g++ -Wall -Wextra` for the first code you'll get `warning: no return statement in function returning non-void` and `warning: unused parameter ‘output’`. (Also `Deck &theDeck` should probably rather be `const Deck &theDeck`. _Const-correctness_ for the win.)